# Forward proxy with rotating IP

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, proxy, apache-2.4, apache-traffic-server

Is it possible to set-up a forward proxy using Apache Traffic Server or nginx, such that it forwards/sends each outgoing request from a different (random) IPv4/IPv6 available on the server?

Answer (score 0):

In Apache, as far selecting which IP address you want to use for the outgoing requests on the proxy you could use:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxysourceaddress

A fairly dirty way of doing this would be to have a bash script that changes the value of "ProxySourceAddress" in your Apache conf file to a different IP address every x amount of seconds. Keep in mind you would probably have to reload (not restart) Apache everytime you changed the value which would probably put considerable load on the server.